# rails: how to design two similar models

Tags: model

A rails 4 application contains 2 models: envelope, package.

The envelope has a quantity field where the package has weight and size and also quantity.

The similarity for this two objects are:
- both are Items to be deliver
- quantity field in both models
- both can have errors
- both belongs to a Shipment object
- and still not sure in the further requirements in the future that will have more similarity...

So, basically I though of two options to model this:

1. STI - Single Table Inheritance - I don't like it because it will force me create null values for "size" when envelope will be stores
2. create class for each of the models - I don't like it neither because the 2 of the models are kind of the same and very similar and I guess they will share code because of their similarity

Your help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second option, "create class for each of the models", sounds more favorable since it follows the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Should you choose a single class for these specified concerns, think about your statement that there may be more requirements in the future. What you are doing now is "Pre-Optimization" or "[Premature Optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)," which often leads to lost time in the long run, and in this case, will make your (single) class more difficult to to expand / modify when these future requirements come along. Right now, as you are developing this application or service, the application is not going to suffer much for having 2 classes / 2 tables to store Packages and Envelopes. Months/years in the future, if this issue is causing a lot of pain in the form of DB load or something similar, you should *then* revisit the need to combine them into one class/table.

---

As far as worrying about the minor architectural elegance gained from having two classes is concerned, keep in mind that these are the kind of things that only *programmers* care about. The application is likely not for you, but for the business' customers. The customers dont observe or care about a reduced number of classes or tables. They just care that their envelopes and packages are delivered. Same for the CEO, investors, and other stakeholders in the application. Its difficult, as a programmer, to let go of these things, but its something we have to do. Dont worry about spending more than a minute or two thinking about very small performance gains unless they already present a problem that needs to be dealt with. Implement the application first, ship the new service/feature, then later iterate on it if there is a *need* for a performance gain.

Comment: very interesting articles and you've got a point here! Thanks!